# Send button in server Side not working TCP C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, tcp

I try to add send button in my server to send data to client the connection is working very well, and send button in client is working good too, Data sent when connection started but when I try to add code under button send _click I get this message :
a request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected.
Here the Server side code "

```
 public partial class Server : Form
{
    public Server()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ListBox.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
        // call server connection method
        connection();
    }


    private Socket _server;
    Socket _client;
    private byte [] _buffer = new byte[1024];
    private Socket client;
    Socket oldConnection;


    /**
     * Server Connection Binding and listening method
     */
    private void connection()
    {
        _server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        try
        {
            _server.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 5020));
            _server.Listen(5);
            // before connecting to any client
            status.Items.Add("Waiting for client...");

            _server.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptConn), _server);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    // Accept Clients Connections
    private void AcceptConn(IAsyncResult iar)
    {
        try
        {
            oldConnection = (Socket)iar.AsyncState;
            client = (Socket)oldConnection.EndAccept(iar);
            // if the socket status is connected
            // add
            // Connected to: clientIP:Portnumber
            status.Items.Add("Connected to: " + client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
            // welcom message from server
            string welcome = "Welcome to my server";
            byte[] welcomeMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(welcome);

            client.BeginSend(welcomeMessage, 0, welcomeMessage.Length,
                SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(SendData), client);

            // Accept next client Connection
            oldConnection.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptConn),oldConnection);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    // create Send callback method to execute the BeginSend() call
    private void SendData(IAsyncResult iar)
    {
        try
        {
            _client = (Socket)iar.AsyncState;
            int sent = _client.EndSend(iar);

            _client.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, 
                new AsyncCallback(ReceiveData), _client);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    // create Receive callback method to execute the BeginReceive() call
    private void ReceiveData(IAsyncResult iar)
    {
        try
        {
            Socket client = (Socket)iar.AsyncState;
            int recv = client.EndReceive(iar);

            if (recv == 0)
            {
                // updating status
                status.Items.Add("Waiting for client...");
                // _server Socket will start Accepting new clients connections
                _server.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptConn), _server);
                return;
            }
            else
            { 
                string receivedData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(_buffer, 0, recv);
                // add message to the ListBox
                results.Items.Add(receivedData);
                // resend client message to the client
                byte[] message2 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(receivedData);

                client.BeginSend(message2, 0, message2.Length, SocketFlags.None,
                    new AsyncCallback(SendData), client);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void Server_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] strMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Server Sending ..");
            client.BeginSend(strMessage, 0, strMessage.Length, SocketFlags.None,
                new AsyncCallback(SendData), client);
            MessageBox.Show("done");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
}
```

I am using Asynchronous TCP C#.

Comment: Having `client` and `_client` fields is a bit confusing. Are you sure you're using the intended client field? Because the one you're using is obviously not connected.

Comment: I tried both but not worked, pls if you see edit to make code alive tell me :(

Answer (score 0):

Your server is set up to accept multiple clients. You should have a separate socket for accepting. Once a client has been accepted you can copy it over to another socket object and add it in a `List<socket>` then reset the accepted socket for the next connection. Currently you try to send a message to a socket that has been reset to accept the next client thus you are getting an error. After you store your connected sockets and have a separate socket for accepting, your send  event  can send the message to a socket stored on the List or to all of them.

```
var clients = new List<socket>();

....

 private void AcceptConn(IAsyncResult iar)
    {
        try
        {
            oldConnection = (Socket)iar.AsyncState;            
            var clientSocket = (Socket)oldConnection.EndAccept(iar);
            clients.Add(clientSocket);
....
```

Comment: Thanks.. but I am very confused so can you write this new socket that shall store current connection .. will be client or _client?

Comment: You have way to many sockets I'm getting confused too now. The stored connection should be client in your case but make sure that client is always a new instance when a new connection is accepted that's why I was recommending to keep them in a list.